# How do I keep F10 from activating menu in AS3 AIR application?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm developing an AIR application in Flash CS5.5 using ActionScript 3. The user must be able to use function keys F1-F10 for custom app-specific functions. They all work great, except F10. I can detect keyUp and keyDown for F10 just fine, but when F10 is released, the application menu receives focus and the app ignores subsequent function key presses until either a)F10 is pressed again, or b)a non-function key is pressed. This happens whether or not I've added a new NativeMenu (I'd prefer the app to NOT have one).

Is there a way to either,

1. Prevent the menu from receiving focus when pressing F10, or
2. Force the focus to return to the content after pressing F10 so that a subsequent function key press will be recognized?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create you own completely custom menu without relying on the default menu items and adding to them, which is what you might have to do in this situation.

You could try [preventing the default event from firing](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#preventDefault%28%29) on mouse up, but that's a bit of a ghetto/hack solution if it even works so i would suggest that instead you build your own native menu items from scratch.  basically it's the same thing as what you are doing, except you have to first remove all the default menu items ("File", "Edit", etc.) and optionally replace them with your own default items.

Comment: +1 But I wouldn't say prevent default is a hack. Prevent default was specifically put in place... to... well... prevent default behavior. lol

Comment: My application will have NO menu at all. The problem is, when F10 is pressed and released, the application shifts focus to the menu. This behavior is the same whether or not I've added an AIR NativeMenu and menu items. So even if no menu is visible along the top edge of the app, the behavior is the same - no other function keys will register until focus comes off the menu (by pressing F10 again or any other non-function keys). I've tried preventDefault, but AIR will not allow keyUp events to be cancelled (and the F10 behavior in questions happens on keyUp).

Comment: Simplest example possible:  
`stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_KeyboardUpHandler);  
function fl_KeyboardUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void{  
keyText.text=("key UP "+event.keyCode); }`  
With a dynamic text box named "keyText" on the stage, test this as an AS 3, AIR 2.3 app. Once you press F10 (key code 121), another function key press will not register until pressing a non-function key (or F10 again).